# Who introduced the finite difference notation using $\Delta$?

Tags: calculus, notation, math-history, finite-differences

We all know that Leibniz introduced the differential notation $dx, dy$, and that in developing his calculus for infinitesimal differences he was inspired by his previous work on *finite* diffences. Today we usually denote such finite differences $\Delta x, \Delta y$. But did Leibniz use this notation? If not, who originated it?

Comment: Does it even matter? The word difference obviously starts with a *d*, so the Greek letter delta seems like an appropriate choice, as does the differential *d* in calculus.

Comment: First uses of mathematical terms are of interest to many people and there is even a well-developed [site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html). The history of notation has also interested many historians, e.g. F. Cajori.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Florian Cajori, *A history of mathematical notations* (1928 - Dover reprint) :

> "A provisional, temporary notation $\Delta$ for *differential coefficient* or *différences
>   des fonctions* was used in 1706 by Johann Bernoulli." (see Cajori, page 205 of 2nd vol).

L.Euler introduced the symbolism for *finite differences* in *Institutiones calculi differentialis* (Petersburgh, 1755), p.3-7 (see Cajori, page 265).